# Brake pedal will not return after being depressed: brake booster diagnosis?

Tags: brakes

After being on holiday for a few weeks, I come home and find that the car brake pedal on my (automatic tranmission with ABS brakes) car will no longer spring back up after depressing it.  After doing a lot of reading, the problem would appear to be either with the brake booster or the master cylinder.  Unfortunately, I can't really tell what might be the issue since I can't find any information that seems to match my specific conditions. There does not appear to be a return spring on the pedal that is missing.

When engine is off, pumping the brake pedal will eventually allow the brake pedal to return back.  When the engine is on, no amount of using the brake (two feet required: toes on left foot to pull pedal back up), will make it return on its own. I have verified that the brakes still have excellent holding power. When the car is on and in drive or reverse, the brake still engages. I have not tried driving with it because I live in a high density urban setting.

Based on the above, I think the problem is somewhere in the brake booster or the booster hose. I'd like to diagnose it, but am not sure how. Pressing down on the brake is easy and doesnt feel any harder or softer than it used to be. However, starting the car with my foot on the brake pedal does not "pull" the brake pedal down an extra few inches.

**Can I remove the booster hose from the engine side and blow or suck to test for a seal problem?** I should only be able to suck air. If I can blow air, I know there is a seal problem. The brake booster hose is not a closed system, is it?

**Is there a return spring in the brake booster that could have failed? Is it possible to diagnose this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out, my car -- a Saab 900NG -- did not appear to have a return spring built into the brake booster.  There doesn't seem to have been any evidence of it though there does appear to be a small auxiliary spring built in to help *apply* the brakes (not disengage them).  The shop merely added a return spring and everything seems fine.  The brakes are not tough, the fluid is fine, the master cylinder was in excellent condition, the booster diaphragm was in one piece, and the hoses were all sound.  The brake lines were also in good condition.

Chalk it up to another Saab-related mystery.  I've had a few of those lately and it makes me want to never have another Saab ever again.

EDIT: It would appear that there may be a return spring on the pedal itself rather than the brake booster.  I am continuing to investigate this.

Answer (score 2):

I would first check the hose - it is rubber, and they do perish from the inside out. Disconnect it from the servo end, and see if you get good suction on it with the engine running.

While you're at it, visually check all the flexi hoses in the braking system for signs of bulging or wear - if any show such signs, replace them all.

The return spring is generally in the back of the master cylinder. If the M/C is working correctly, the brakes should, with the engine off, behave correctly, but be harder to push. If they don't, replace that first. Have you seen any signs of fluid loss? In particular, is the level dropping with no obvious leaks? Master Cylinders can leak into the servo, with the fluid then attacking the diaphragm inside...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The hoses are all fine and there is no fluid loss. Brake have good holding power without having to muscle them down.  I think it may be a combination of problems all stemming within the brake booster.  I will respond as soon as I find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plastic bushing on break pedal that sticks i lubed it and it started working but just replace that should solve the pedal problem that is what i am hoping

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted. It seems like a helpful suggestion.

Comment: I took this comment as inspiration, and was able to fix my problem of the brake pedal not returning all the way by pulling back the boot from the linkage (under the horn) and put some WD40 on it. Worked like a charm. I sprayed under the boot where the linkage goes into towards the trunk compartment. I have a 1999 Porsche Boxster

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at where the brake pedal connects to the booster. The rod that connects to the brake pedal has a spring in the middle where the cover is. Use a flashlight and you'll see what I'm talking about. If you spray some WD-40 on the spring and rod it will free it up and allow it to move freely again. I had the exact same problem on a 2006 Jetta. Hope it helps someone out there.